# How can I define more color commands properly for \pslegend in pst-plot

Tags: color, pstricks, pst-plot

I am plotting a multi-curve graph by using pst-plot, and naturally need different color to label each curve in legend, by using `\pslegend` command. However, I find I can only use a number of pre-defined color commands

```
\red \blue \black \green \cyan \yellow \gray % ...may be more
```

When I looked into the `pstricks` package documentation and tried to define my own color command

```
\newrgbcolor{myorg}{255 165 0} % trying to define a orange color command
```

however, it does not work, here is an MWE (compile by using `xelatex`, Windows 64-bit, TeX Live 2015)

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[border = 1.2cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\newrgbcolor{myorg}{255 165 0}

\begin{document}

\pslegend[rt]{ \myorg\rule[1ex]{2em}{1pt} & Line 1) }
\begin{psgraph}(0,0)(5,5){10cm}{8cm}
\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

[image]
The color is exactly like using `\yellow`.

How can I define a color command properly (for the use of `\pslegend` in pst-plot), and where am I able to look up all the pre-defined color commands in pstricks (can't find a list of color commands in both `pstricks` and `pst-plot` package documents)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pstricks` loads the `xcolor` package. If you want a broader choice,  pass the option, say, `x11names` to xcolor  (via `\documentclass`). This option gives access to nearly 320 predefined colours. See § 4, *Colors by Names*, pp38–40 of the documentation. You also can use the option `svgnames` which more or less the same as HTML colour names.

Example:

```
\documentclass[x11names, border = 1.2cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\pslegend[rt]{ \color{SeaGreen3}\rule[0.5ex]{2em}{1pt} & Line 1) }
\begin{psgraph}(0,0)(5,5){10cm}{8cm}
\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried in this direction in different ways after seeing that, but still not make it work. Could you please give a working example that shows how the method works, specifically for `\pslegend` in a plot with `pst-plot`. Let us say I want an orange color, or purple, for my curve color in legend box

Comment: @Spaceship: I've added an example (sorry for the colour, but you can change that easily).

Comment: The `\color` command works perfectly, and solve the problem. Big help of you, Cheers!